# Resource route (edit ) redirecting to 404 page laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've created  a resource

`Route::resource('page-category', 'PageCategoryController',['except'=>['create'] ]);`

code in view:

```
<a href="{{ route('page-category.edit',$pcategory->id) }}" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:20px;">Edit</a>
```

and my edit method in `PageCategoryController.php`

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $pcategory = PageCategory::find($id);
    return view('admin.page-category.show')->withPcategory($pcategory);
}
```

when i click the button in the view it redirectes to my 404 view. When i hover over the button the link is like `http://localhost:8000/page-category//edit` . When i manually insert id number in link `http://localhost:8000/page-category/1/edit` it does takes me to edit page.

Comment: It would seem `$pcategory` does not have an ID, most likely because it hasn't been saved to the database.  How are you passing that variable to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to routing guide on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

```
<a href="{{ route('page-category.edit',['page-category' => $pcategory->id]) }}" class="btn btn-block btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:20px;">Edit</a>
```

Comment: try clearing a cache tell me what do you see when you hover the link

Comment: This is using javascript objects in PHP.

Comment: if nothing works change your link to {{ URL::to('page-category/' . $pcategory->id . '/edit') }}

Comment: Firstly you have an error in your suggested code  after `$pcategory->id` there should be `))` brackets you have written `})`. I couldn't edit it because there must me 6 character change to edit. After fixing your error, i came to another error with your code `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' `

Comment: {{ route('page-category.edit',['page-category' => $pcategory->id]) }}

Comment: Same error (redirected to 404) and same url `http://localhost:8000/page-category//edit` with your second suggested code.

Comment: Still same error. I think there is conflict between other route.

Comment: did you try this: {{ URL::to('page-category/' . $pcategory->id . '/edit') }}

Comment: I tried it by making manual get route also but didn't work. same error

Comment: check this out https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

What if your controller becomes:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $pcategory = PageCategory::find($id);
    return view('admin.page-category.show')->compact('pcategory');
}
```

So this will send the `$pcategory`, in this case your page category with the id (`$id`), to your view.

From there you'll be able access to your route `page-category.edit` by sending it the id of the page category: `$pCategory->id` just like you did.